# Vertically centering image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know there are a ton of posts about this issue. After reading all them I feel like I am close, but it still isn't working for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rthFtAb.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.product {
    height:225px;
    min-height:225px;
    max-width:220px;
    background-color:#ff00ff;

}

.image {
    min-height:225px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.image img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/SBqU5/</kbd>

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate/similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css ; in your code sample, the use of `vertical-align` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `display:table-cell;` and `max-width;` parent should be `display:table;` `table-layout:fixed` and `width:xxpx`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SBqU5/1/)**

```
.product {
    height:225px;
    width:220px;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.image {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.image img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Six methods for centering something vertically.Pick your poison. Your method would fall under the "Table" option.

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Line-height

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="image.png" alt="" />
</div>

#parent {
    line-height: 200px;
}

#parent img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Table

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {display: table;}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Negative Margins

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {position: relative;}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

Stretching

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {position: relative;}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Equal Padding

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {
    padding: 5% 0;
}

#child {
    padding: 10% 0;
}
```

Floater Div

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floater"></div>
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {height: 250px;}

#floater {
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

#child {
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to define a width and height to your image, you can use `position: absolute'.

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;

}

.image img {
    width: 220px;
    height: 105px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -110px;
    margin-top: -52px;

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SBqU5/3/)

Note that the negative left and top margins are half of their width and height, respectively.