# Making div vertically centered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align center a div in bootstrap `<header>` but it does not work (please before voting down visit JSFiddle link!):

```
<div style="display: table-cell; height: 50px; vertical-align: middle;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbtn">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbtn" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbar-search">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-search-btn" >
            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
        </button>
        <input type="search" class="navsearch" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I remove `navbar-search` div buttons are fine.
[image]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/Rp94k/1/

Note: Search container has `display:inline-block;` and makes it stick to the top, I can't remove it.

Comment: Duplicate (one of many); see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918443/vertically-centering-image/24918655#24918655 . In this situation your div (navbar-search) may likely be display: block...so it can't be in a single line with the button elements.

Comment: No it's not the same. Search container div has ```display:inline-block;```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<header class="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid expanded-panel">
            <div class="row" dir="rtl">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    3

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div style="display: table;">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbtn">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbtn" >
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div id="navbar-search" style="display: table-cell;">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-search-btn" >
                                <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                            </button>
                            <input type="search" class="navsearch" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
```

css

```
.navbar{
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom:#eee solid 1px;
}
.navbtn {
    font-size:large;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.navsearch{
    text-align: right;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
    outline: none;
    background: #eee;
    cursor: inherit;
    display:inline-block;
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
    height:35px;
}
#navbar-search{
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.navbar-search-btn{
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    border:none;
    background: #eee;
    height:35px;

}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/monzoor/TC9UH/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.navbar-btn` to buttons to vertically center them. See [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons) for further details.

Semantically if it's a nav it should be in a nav HTML5 element. Anyway, your columns are too wide and are pushing down the icons (columns taking up 100% of the width leave no room for anything else).

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aibrean/VwNA7/) using pretty much base Bootstrap

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 navbar-right">
            <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                              </i>
                          </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form><!--/form-->
          </div><!--/form column-->
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbtn navbar-btn">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span>
              </button> 
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbtn  navbar-btn" >
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
              </button>
            </div><!--/buttons column-->
            </div><!--/row column-->
        </div><!--/right column-->
      </div><!--/row-->
   </div><!--/container-->
</nav> <!--/nav-->
```

Comment: I think you did not check the JSFiddle link!

Comment: I updated the code and included a fiddle link. You can adjust parent columns as needed.

Comment: Well, actually you are using default navbar control, that I pretend to not use it.